# Port Forwarding to vboxnet0 with saving client's real IP

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, iptables, network-bridge

I set up the internet on a virtual machine that is running through VirtualBox and set up port forwarding. First, in rt_tables of Host Machine (iproutes2) I added this:

```
100 vm0
```

Then I run this:

```bash
ip rule add from 192.168.56.100 table vm0
ip route add default dev eth0 via 10.0.1.1 table vm0
```

192.168.56.100 is VM's local IP address. 10.0.1.1 is my gateway. And also 192.168.56.1 is Host's local IP address in "Host-Only" adapter.

And then iptables settings on Host

```bash
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface vboxnet0 --out-interface eth0 --source 192.168.56.100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface eth0 --out-interface vboxnet0 --destination 192.168.56.100 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vboxnet0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o vboxnet0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 15:1722 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.100
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1724:65530 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.100
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 15:1722 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.100
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1724:65530 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.100
```

Sorry. Maybe some iptables rules are redundant here.

The VM has internet connection through "Host-Only" adapter and can accept all connections on forwarded ports. The problem is that Host doesn't say to VM client's real IP address. VM receives 192.168.56.1 instead of client's real IP. Example:

```bash
root@vm:~# lsof -i :22 -n
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd       691 root    3u  IPv4   21232      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       691 root    4u  IPv6   21234      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd    996826 root    4u  IPv4 2857061      0t0  TCP 192.168.56.100:22->192.168.56.1:61441 (ESTABLISHED)
```